# Decimal to binary tensor conversion

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to convert a one-hot tensor to a 8-binary tensor array. I'm using tf.keras.backend.argmax to find the decimal index which I'd like to convert to a binary representation.

When using tf.keras.backend.constant list, the following code works perfectly.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    a_dec = tf.constant([0,1,2], dtype=tf.int32)
    a_bin = tf.mod(tf.bitwise.right_shift(tf.expand_dims(a_dec,1), tf.range(8)), 2)
    out = sess.run(a_bin)
print(out)
```

output:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

However, when I try something like the following

```py
sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    a_dec = K.constant([0,1,2], dtype=tf.int32)
    index = K.constant([K.argmax(a_dec)], dtype=tf.int32)
    a_bin = tf.mod(tf.bitwise.right_shift(tf.expand_dims(index,1), tf.range(8)), 2)
    out = sess.run(a_bin)
print(out)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Expected float32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.
```

So, how do I make an *argmax* tensor to work just like a *constant* tensor?